# My UWP is not working on windows 10 1803 version

Tags: uwp, windows-10

My UWP is not working on windows 10 1803 version.. it is working properly on higher version 1809

Application able to install.but after launch.. full application get white all UI wipeout.. full blank on 1803 and it is working on 1809

My Target Version:- 1803

MIn Version:- 1803

Comment: Could you create a new blank UWP project(target and min version is 1803) to test on windows 10 1803 to see if you still face the same issue?